# Problema con consulta a tabla con inner join

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

Tengo un problema espero alguien pueda ayudarme porque me estoy volviendo loco y no logro resolverlo.

Tengo el siguiente código que utilizo para consultar a una tabla y mostrar los resultados en un datatable:

---

```
$joinQuery = "FROM orders INNER JOIN clients on (client_id=order_cid) INNER JOIN users on user_id=order_responsible";

$extraCondition = "orders.order_type in ({$tramites}) or REPLACE(CONCAT(clients.client_name,clients.client_lastname), ' ', '') LIKE '%{$filter_fullname}%' or orders.order_deadline LIKE '%{$fecha}%' or orders.order_date_start LIKE '%{$fecha}%' or users.user_name LIKE '%{$valueRequestSearch}%'";
```

---

Lo que necesito es order por un nuevo campo "order_status".

Lo que intente fue:

---

```
$joinQuery = "FROM orders INNER JOIN clients on (client_id=order_cid) INNER JOIN users on user_id=order_responsible";

$states = '1,2,3,4,5';
$extraCondition = "orders.order_state IN ({$states}) or orders.order_type in ({$tramites}) or REPLACE(CONCAT(clients.client_name,clients.client_lastname), ' ', '') LIKE '%{$filter_fullname}%' or orders.order_deadline LIKE '%{$fecha}%' or orders.order_date_start LIKE '%{$fecha}%' or users.user_name LIKE '%{$valueRequestSearch}%'";
```

---

El código modificado no tira error pero tampoco lista bien en el datatable.
Es decir me sigue listando todos los registros y solo necesito que liste los que tengan un status igual a 1,2,3,4,5.

Espero haberme explicado correctamente.

El código completo aquí:
https://pastebin.com/W66B9LnZ

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ya probaste imprimiendo la consulta y luego copiándola y pegándola en la consola de SQL ?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que usas **OR** para nueva condición y como las demás condiciones se cumplen lo que esta pasando es que en lugar de restringir la consulta la estas ampliando.

Literalmente estas diciendo al manejador todo lo anterior mas los que tengan order_state (1,2,3,4,5)

Utiliza AND de la siguente forma:

```
$joinQuery = "FROM orders INNER JOIN clients on (client_id=order_cid) INNER JOIN users on user_id=order_responsible";

$states = '1,2,3,4,5';
$extraCondition = "orders.order_state IN ({$states}) AND ( orders.order_type in ({$tramites}) or REPLACE(CONCAT(clients.client_name,clients.client_lastname), ' ', '') LIKE '%{$filter_fullname}%' or orders.order_deadline LIKE '%{$fecha}%' or orders.order_date_start LIKE '%{$fecha}%' or users.user_name LIKE '%{$valueRequestSearch}%')";
```

Saludos.